# there was an error managing chromedriver linux64 (for input string: "linux64")

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

```
17:10:40.226 [main] DEBUG io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - Driver to be downloaded chromedriver linux64
17:10:40.229 [main] ERROR io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager - There was an error managing chromedriver linux64 (For input string: "linux64")
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "linux64"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
```

Description of the problem: I am getting below exception while running the test in chrome:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "public"
```

- Browser and version: Browser Version of Chrome : Version 123.0.6312.59
- Operating system and architecture: Windows 11 & 64 Bit
- Selenium version: 3.141.59
- WebDriverManager version: 4.4.3

WebDriverManager call:

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().clearDriverCache().setup();
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selenium version `3.141.59` is way too old to support latest browser versions.

Upgrade to latest selenium(`4.18.1`).

And if you upgrade to latest selenium, you don't need `WebDriverManager` to handle the chrome drivers. [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) will do browser driver management automatically.

Java code to initialise `driver` and launch browser can be as simple as:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
driver.quit();
```

Imports:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```

Answer (score -1):

Issue started with WebDriverManager version 5.6.0, with exception below:

Caused by: io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.config.WebDriverManagerException:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "linux64"

First Try with the below code snippets

**

```
public class ChromeDriverManager(){
protected WebDriver driver;
public void initializeDriver(){
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
    options.addArguments("--lang=en");
    options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
    options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
    options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
    options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().clearDriverCache().setup();
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    ....
}
```

}

**

if getting same issue then try with the below code snippets

**

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().clearDriverCache().setup();
```

**

also for the same problem you've to **

```
**update webdrivermanager to version 5.6.4**
```

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35811225)

Comment: @azdle: This reads like an answer to me. Why do you believe it’s a clarification of the question? Is that just because it starts with the error that set the author on this path?

Comment: I may be reading it wrong, but as far as I can tell this answer is the OP saying they're seeing a slightly different error after switching to a new version of a library, which should be an edit to the original question.

Comment: It seems to be an answer, but maybe that could be made a bit more clear.